# Disable salesforce lightning error dialog

Tags: lightning-aura-components, debugging

Coming from a traditional javascript development world, i'm stumped by how to debug lightning components. Any javascript error is caught by the salesforce handler in aura and shows up in this dialog, which is devoid of ANY useful information such as stack trace and call graph.

[image: custom salesforce error dialog]

Is there a way to disable this so that I can go back to my traditional chrome dev tools where I can use "pause on exception" and have useful error info to debug my lightning components?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the debugger statement to stop processing and open up the browser based tools.

getOpps : function(component) {
    debugger; // the JS debugger will pause here
    var action = component.get("c.getOppInfos");

you should read this article ..

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/03/debugging-lightning-components.html

That message is the lightning frameworks saying it has an error.. Was not made to be a debug output..

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the other answer ,another helpful tool to debug is [chrome extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/inspector_intro.htm)

It comes with perfomance logs ,Event logging ,Component Tree ,Transactions Tab, Actions Tab and Storage Tab .

You can read more [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/inspector_use.htm)

You can install from [chrome store](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/inspector_install.htm)